# Will revoking .p8 key invalidate existing FCM tokens?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I have an app in production that's heavily dependent on push notifications, and I'm worrying that revoking the old .p8 key will invalidate the existing FCM tokens. Unfortunately I can't get the old .p8 key from previous developer, so revoking is the only option. I couldn't find the answer in Firebase documentation. Any ideas?